# which Linux command allows to browse all available smb shares in the network?

Tags: linux, samba

I want to browse all available smb shares in the network, like clicking the "network" in nautilus then all shares are shown, using command line

the closest one I got is smbclient -L SRVNAME, which lists all shares in SRVNAME as well as all other servers in the workgroup and other workgroups available, but it requires me knowing at least the correct SRVNAME

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `smbtree` command to see all the clients & shared folders in a tree fashion.

Comment: Something wrong with the command. While *dolphin* shows really *a lot* of smb directories, `smbtree` only shows a single, which is also local.

Answer (score 2):

I use findsmb It works similar to smbtree.

- smbtree will show you a list of all available workgroups and clients under those work groups.

> $smbtree
>   Enter usernames's password:

```
WORKGROUP1
    \\host1         
        \\host1\ADMIN$          IPC Service (SMB Server)
        \\host1\IPC$            IPC Service (SMB Server)
        \\host1\print$          
        \\host1\print           Printer
    \\host2                 
        \\host2\C$              Default share
        \\host2\ADMIN$          Remote Admin
        \\host2\Z$              Default share
WORKGROUP2
```

- smbfind will show you a list of all client that are advertising them selves as available.

> $findsmb
>
> ```
>                             *=DMB
>                             +=LMB
> ```
>
> ### IP ADDR  |   NETBIOS NAME  |  WORKGROUP/OS/VERSION
>
> 192.168.1.1   DOMAINHOST    *[DOMAIN] [Windows 5.0] [Windows 2000 LAN Manager]